# Adding ArcGIS Desktop map in WordPress web page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wordpress

I have designed a map in ArcGIS Desktop but I do not know how can I add it to a WordPress web site.

How can I do this?

Comment: you have designed it in arcgis dekstop? do you have arcgis server license?

Comment: If you had designed it in ArcGIS Online then this would help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/arcgis/  If I have incorrectly assigned Desktop to ArcGIS based on your [tag:arcgis-desktop] tag when maybe it was Online just use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it.